# Unable to access Mac OS X Lion server on web

Tags: osx-server, server.app

I have the Mac OS X Lion server and am able to view on my iMac, however when I go on a different computer i am unable to see it. 
website: wiki.piezosystems.org

Comment: I'm guessing from the limited information here that your DNS is not set up correctly.

Comment: how should i setup the DNS

Comment: just put your picture on a sharing site and post a link. You can flag it for a moderator to embed the link if needed or just wait until a reader with edit authority notices the link. In the mean time, do check the server app to try changing the local host name to match wiki.piezosystems.org - I see your DNS for www. but not wiki. so you might need to check DNS records to point to wiki.

Comment: You probably need to enter a CNAME record for _wiki_ pointing to the server at _piezosystems.org_  FWIW getting DNS **right** is the most important thing in getting your server to work correctly.

Comment: Yeah and if it's your local host you can't access? I can get access to the default website that comes with the Lion Server but when I add new ones to use as development sites, I can't get to them. It's driving me batty... Every now and then it will work but most of the time it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to be able to access the website on your internal network, you can add the IP address of your server to the list of DNS servers:

[image]